# SERVER_OPERATION_ENCRYPTION_LEVEL missing from SSISDB catalog_properties

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssis, ssis-2014

I'm using MSSQL 2014 (build 12.0.6439.10, named instance) with SSIS 12.0 and trying to execute a package that I've successfully imported into the SSISDB catalog, but when I attempt to run it via a SQL Agent job, I get the following error:

> The value for the Integration Services server property, 'SERVER_OPERATION_ENCRYPTION_LEVEL', is not valid.

Looking in `SSISDB.[catalog].catalog_properties`, the row for this setting doesn't even exist, so I tried to run the following code to set it:

```
GO
ALTER DATABASE [SSISDB] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH NO_WAIT;
GO
USE [SSISDB]
GO
DECLARE @ret int;
EXEC @ret = [internal].[cleanup_server_log];
SELECT @ret;
GO
DECLARE @ret2 int;
EXEC @ret2 = [catalog].[configure_catalog] 'SERVER_OPERATION_ENCRYPTION_LEVEL', '2';
SELECT @ret2;
GO
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [SSISDB] SET  MULTI_USER WITH NO_WAIT;
GO
```

That only returned this error:

> Msg 27163, Level 16, State 1, Procedure configure_catalog, Line 384 [Batch Start Line 58]
> The value for the Integration Services server property, 'SERVER_OPERATION_ENCRYPTION_LEVEL', is not valid. In Management Studio, in the Integration Services Properties dialog box, enter a valid value for this property.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find the Integration Services Properties dialog box. I've tried right-clicking and selecting 'Properties' on SSISDB itself in the SSMS Object Explorer, the Integration Services Catalog folder in the SSMS Object Explorer and all of its sub-items, and every item in the SSMS Object Explorer when connected directly to Integration Services, and none of them have that name or have that property available to edit anywhere in them.

Can I just manually insert this row? Is there something else I've missed somewhere? Any advice or knowledge would be helpful, thanks!

Per request from Dan Guzman, here is the output from `EXEC [catalog].check_schema_version` with `@use32bitruntime` both set to 0 and set to 1 (the output was the same for both):

```
SERVER_BUILD    SCHEMA_VERSION  SCHEMA_BUILD    ASSEMBLY_BUILD  SHARED_COMPONENT_VERSION    COMPATIBILITY_STATUS
12.0.6439.10    3               12.0.2000.8     12.0.2000.0     12.0.2000.8                 0
```

Comment: Add the output of `EXEC catalog.check_schema_version @use32bitruntime = 0` and `EXEC catalog.check_schema_version @use32bitruntime = 1` to your question.

Comment: @DanGuzman edited